# How to create a drag gesture in any direction in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to detect a gesture in *@Composable*, which will allow me to drag an element across the screen in any direction.

I tried using *LongPressDragObserver* but after dragging for a bit, it snaps to a single *Orientation* (either *Horizontally* or *Vertically*) and *Offset* doesn't change for the other *Orientation* at all (it will equal to 0 all the time)

Example functionality I want to achieve:
Long press on the FAB and drag it around the screen so that it's position is constantly under user's finger.

I'm using Compose ***1.0.0-alpha04***

Example code which drags in only one direction (thanks to [Rafsanjani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5430306/rafsanjani))

```
.dragGestureFilter(dragObserver = object : DragObserver { 
  override fun onDrag(dragDistance: Offset): Offset { 
    val newX = dragDistance.x + verticalOffset.value 
    val newY = dragDistance.y + horizontalOffset.value 
    verticalOffset.value = newX 
    horizontalOffset.value = newY 
    return dragDistance 
  } 
})
```

Comment: "I tried using LongPressDragObserver but after dragging for a bit, it snaps to a single Orientation (either Horizontally or Vertically) and Offset doesn't change for the other Orientation at all (it will equal to 0 all the time)" -- nobody can help debug code that they cannot see. A [mcve] would increase the likelihood that somebody can assist you.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been closed. Modifier.draggable() only drags in one orientation at a time. You can't have diagonal drags with it which is what the OP is asking

Comment: @CommonsWare 
    .dragGestureFilter(dragObserver = object : DragObserver {
                override fun onDrag(dragDistance: Offset): Offset {
                    val newX = dragDistance.x + verticalOffset.value
                    val newY = dragDistance.y + horizontalOffset.value

                    verticalOffset.value = newX
                    horizontalOffset.value = newY
                    return dragDistance
                }

                })

Comment: check https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/ui/ui/integration-tests/ui-demos/src/main/java/androidx/compose/ui/demos/gestures/PopupDragDemo.kt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Modifier.pointerInput` with `detectDragGestures` to do exactly the same as you want.

Example:

```
   @Composable
fun Drag2DGestures() {
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(400.dp) }
    val offsetX = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val offsetY = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(size)){
        Box(
                Modifier
                        .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.value.roundToInt(), offsetY.value.roundToInt()) }
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                        .size(50.dp)
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                                change.consumeAllChanges()
                                offsetX.value = (offsetX.value + dragAmount.x)
                                        .coerceIn(0f, size.width.toFloat() - 50.dp.toPx())

                                offsetY.value = (offsetY.value + dragAmount.y)
                                        .coerceIn(0f, size.height.toFloat() - 50.dp.toPx())
                            }
                        }
        )
        Text("Drag the box around", Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    }
}
```

will produce this result:

ٍٍٍ*Sorry for the jank/drop in frames, the built-in emulator recorder cannot record 60fps smoothly*

[image]

Compose version: alpha-11

Comment: Where is `size` set? I see it initialized to zero, and then later you are using it's `.width` and `.height` to constrain the amount of drag motion.

Comment: You can use something like: `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned` before `pointerInput` call and set the `size` to size given in `onGloballyPositioned` lambda (which is 50 dp here). FYI, if you copy-paste the code above it will work like a charm

Comment: `var size by remember { mutableStateOf(400.dp) }` doesn't work anymore, gives an error "Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate".

Comment: you're missing `import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue`, you'll have to import set value as well because `size` is `var`, so add this import: `import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue`

Comment: @MR3YY yes, that fixed it, thanks

Comment: please update your answer, `pointerInput` is different than yours

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to make any component draggable:

```
@Composable
fun DraggableComponent(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val offset = remember { mutableStateOf(IntOffset.Zero) }
    Box(
        content = { content() },
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset { offset.value }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()
                    val offsetChange = IntOffset(dragAmount.x.roundToInt(), dragAmount.y.roundToInt())
                    offset.value = offset.value.plus(offsetChange)
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Use it like this:

```
DraggableComponent {
    FloatingActionButton(
       ...
    )
}
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#dragging